# Negative lookahead in LR parsing algorithm

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers

Consider such a rule in grammar for an LR-family parsing generator (e.g YACC, BISON, etc.):

`Nonterminal : [ lookahead not in {Terminal1, ..., TerminalN} ] Rule ;`

It's an ordinary rule, except that it has a restriction: a phrase produced with this rule cannot begin with `Terminal1, ..., TerminalN`. (Surely, this rule can be replaced with a set of usual rules, but it will result in a bigger grammar). This can be useful for resolving conflicts.

The question is, is there a modification of LR table construction algorithm that accepts such restrictions? It seems to me that such a modification is possible (like precedence relations).

Surely, it can be checked in runtime, but I mean compile-time check (a check which is performed while building parsing table, like `%prec`, `%left`, `%right` and `%nonassoc` directives in yacc-compartible generators.)

Comment: I'm not clear whether this a  question about the tools in practice, or the LR parsing strategy in the abstract world. Also, the title mislead me: I thought you wanted like $-5$ symbols lookahead.

Comment: Seems that the phrase "negative lookahead" is common use in regard to regular expressions. The question is about abstract theory, but it would be very useful in real world parsing (e.g., consider ECMA-262 grammar, http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1, section 12.4). I would very much appreciate any formal or informal proof or practical experience whether it is possible to implement such restrictions and how to do that.

Comment: Okay. You say yourself, "this rule can be replaced with a set of usual rules". What remains to say?

Comment: This fact neither means that negative lookahead in LR parsing is useless, nor that it is possible, so I don't see what you mean. :)

Comment: You claim yourself that there is a (straight-forward) construction to unfold the "negative lookahead" into regular rules, so a parser-generator can just do that, can't it

Comment: Surely, but there's one problem. As I said, "this rule can be replaced with a set of usual rules, but it will result in a bigger grammar". Bigger grammar means bigger parser, and I want a "cheap" version. ( It's very much like like precedence relations: parser and grammar remain of the same size, but conflicts are resolved properly.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is such a modification. A negative lookahead assertion at the END of a production means taking special care in computing FOLLOW sets. Before a terminal makes no sense. Before a nonterminal is a bit more complicated: the optimal strategy depends on the context. Special care while generating the shift relationship is part of the answer. On balance, this is an algorithm design problem more than a theoretical computer science problem.